# Back button in Cocos2d-x 3.2 Android

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to detect back button press event on Android with Cocos2d-x 3.2.
I research some topic, but these ways are for Cocos2d-x 2.x, it is deprecate in 3.2 version.
I tried with

```
listener_ = EventListenerKeyboard::create();
listener_->onKeyPressed = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameOverScene::onKeyPressed, this);
_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener_, this);
```

But nothing is detected.

Can you help me, please !

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my problem

```
auto listener = EventListenerKeyboard::create();
listener->onKeyReleased = [](EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event){
    Director::getInstance()->end();
};

_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
```

Thanks a lot!